# Restlet : Router with RoleAuthorizer : routes does not work

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet

i'm trying to use Restlet on GAE. I have a guard followed by the root router. 2 roleAuthorizer, one for the admin and a the other for the users. then 2 router behind the roleauthorizer for the routes between uri and the ressource classes. It's strange because, the route doesn't work. If i use the attachDefault it's ok but for the routes with attach : nothing !

here is my code :

```
public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot() {

         Router rootRouter = new Router(getContext());

    pubRouter = new Router(getContext());

    String version="/book/v"+System.getProperty("API_VERSION");
    pubRouter.attachDefault(BookRessource.class);
    pubRouter.attach(version+"/book",BookRessource.class);

     RoleAuthorizer ra1 = new RoleAuthorizer();
     ra1.getAuthorizedRoles().add(MyEnroler.DEVELOPER);
     ra1.getAuthorizedRoles().add(MyEnroler.ADMINISTRATOR);
     ra1.setNext(pubRouter);       

     rootRouter.attach(version, ra1);

     adminRouter = new Router(getContext());

String developerVersion="/admin/v1";
    adminRouter.attach(developerVersion+"/developer", DeveloperRessource.class);
    adminRouter.attach(developerVersion+"/method",MethodRessource.class);

RoleAuthorizer ra2 = new RoleAuthorizer();
    ra2.getAuthorizedRoles().add(MyEnroler.ADMINISTRATOR);
    ra2.setNext(adminRouter);
    rootRouter.attach(developerVersion, ra2); 

    ChallengeAuthenticator guard=
       new ChallengeAuthenticator( getContext(),ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC,"OPA");
    guard.setVerifier(new MyVerifier());
    guard.setEnroler(new MyEnroler());
    guard.setNext(rootRouter);
    return guard;

 }
```

and an extract of my "web.xml" :

```
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

if i want try this : http://domain.appspot.com/api/book/v1/book, i received a 404 error.
can you help me ?